# Extract Values from Cells > Sum the Values > Multiply the Values

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have two sheets in my Google spreadsheet, "*input*" and "*output*".
On my "*input*" sheet I have multiple values,
which always have a certain letter in front of them.

On the other sheet "*output*" I want to add all values together for each letter
and then be able to multiply this result with another value.

The values sometimes are whole numbers, other times they hav decimal places.

I tried the following functions to extract only the number without the letter,
but then the extracted value was not a number that I could continue to use for other math functions such as multiplications.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(XX;"[0-9]+")

=REGEXEXTRACT(XX;"[0-9]*\.[0-9]+")

=REGEXEXTRACT(XX; "\d+")

=SUM(SPLIT(XX;CONCATENATE(SPLIT(XX;".0123456789"))))^
```

If I tried to use "=VALUE(XX)" I got a weird number.

Also this formulars are only for one cell,
but I want the formula to work on the whole "input" sheet.

Therefor it must be used in combination with something like

```
=SUMIF('input'!A:Z; "XXXX"; 'input'!A:Z)
```

...at least this is my best guess.

I linked a sample sheet below, can you help me out guys?

Many thanks in advance!

[Google Spreadsheet Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WXUIrniSnwm0ARO-otIKVlqIRW2PkuG-zN667xe6Fb0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the sum of the cells which have letter "E" at the beginning, try the following formula:

```
=sum(arrayformula(iferror(regexextract(input!A1:H100,"E ([\d.+]*)")*1)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working! I will try to analyze your formula to understand whats different from my approach. I keep the Spreadsheet Test File online for others to view the solution.